# Bootstrap MaxLength indicator badge plugin not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use this Bootstrap MaxLength plugin (http://mimo84.github.io/bootstrap-maxlength/) in my angularjs project but it is not working. Can anyone please help me if you have used it already?

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="txtdummy" maxlength="25" />
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input#txtdummy').maxlength({ alwaysShow: true });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working it's because it's a jQuery plugin. To make it work you need to define an angularjs directive where to make the functionality to work. I would suggest write one yourself or ask the author to make the directive for you.